# How to install cocos2dx on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, 13.04, games, c++

I have Ubuntu 13.04  on my laptop. I need to  install cocos2dx on it. Does any one know how to install it?

Please explain how to install.

Comment: Did you try: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_run_HelloWorld_and_tests_on_linux

Comment: yes,i did. But this link contents are very old.They have explained for version 1. but right now cocos2dx is version 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are tutorials already made for it.

check this one:

[Installation of cocos 2dx](http://chanchal1971.blogspot.de/2012/09/installing-cocos2d-x-on-ubuntu-1204.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 17.04**

After / if my two patches below get merged, usage will be trivial:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x
cd cocos2d-x
git checkout 7350aeca8cf2c5bea3c3484d50202bf13cc18041
./build/install-deps-linux.sh
./download-deps.py
mkdir build-make
cd build-make
cmake ..
make -j`nproc`
./bin/cpp-tests/cpp-tests
```

Before the merge, just copy paste 
the modified files from `cocos2d-x-3rd-party-libs-bin` to `external/`:

- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3rd-party-libs-bin/pull/303
- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3rd-party-libs-bin/pull/304

`install-deps-linux.sh` changes your gcc and g++ update alternatives... but all compiles fine with the default GCC version on Ubuntu 17.04, and appear to exist only to upgrate Travis' GCC from 4.8 to 4.9...

So either comment out those lines https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/18389 or after running the script do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc "/usr/bin/gcc-6" 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ "/usr/bin/g++-$v" 10
```